# Can't build hello world in C++ with Code::Blocks (20.03), OS: Linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I am looking to learn a new language, **C++**,  but I experience some difficulties with **Code::Blocks** 20.03 (CB). I am currently running CB on my DELL XPS 13-9360 with Linux, **Ubuntu** 20.04.1 LTS. I installed CB with the instructions on this site: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/03/install-codeblocks-20-03-ubuntu-18-04/ using `sudo apt install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib`.

Now, I create a new project on CB, keeping the default options (with GNU GCC Compiler), but when I try to build the main.cpp file (**hello world**), there is this error message:

obj/Debug/main.o: no such file or directory
error: no input files.

[image: Here is a screenshot from my IDE:]

You can also see the properties of my project for Debug and advanced options:
[Build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm30r.png)
[Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRDlp.png)

Here is my installed packages list (got it with `dpkg --list | grep c++`):
[Packages_list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGiEs.png)

Thanks already for any help you could bring me, and let me know if there is some missing information that you need to help me.

L.R.

Comment: The path at the bottom of your screenshot seems kind of broken. Is there anything useful in the build log tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you were bitten by [this code::blocks bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/993/), which seems to have been plaguing Code::Blocks for a while now:

> #993 Will not compile sources on build if path contains international characters

You can try renaming your homework directory from "École" to "Ecole" to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Very strange, but I works now. I did not think it would be so simple. Thank you very much.